# Trying to remove apache2/httpd and installing mod_perl

Tags: server, apt, package-management, apache2, perl

It started with me trying to install Apache and mod_perl by following [this guide](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/install/install.html#Apache).

However, foolishly I installed Apache by using `sudo apt-get install apache2`, which installed 2.4 on my system.

After running `perl Makefile.PL <options>` as per the instructions, I got the same error as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128015/installing-mod-perl-2-0-7-on-apache-httpd-2-4-2).

It told me I should uninstall 2.4 and install 2.2 instead, which is what I tried to do by doing `sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2`.

When I ran `which apache2` it returned nothing so I assumed it was gone, but when I ran `which httpd` (which gave a line) and then `httpd -V`, it gave me:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug  6 2014 20:38:13
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:36
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1-dev, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1-dev, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT=""
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/conf/httpd.conf"
```

So I tried to remove httpd with `sudo apt-get remove httpd` but one of the messages was `Virtual packages like 'httpd' can't be removed`.

Now I'm really scared to install/remove anything else on my Ubuntu system as I really have no idea what I'm doing. How can I completely remove the Apache/httpd/whatever 2.4 server and install only the 2.2 so it'll let me install mod_perl?

I went [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html) to follow their steps but after receiving the same error from trying to run the perl makefile as before I tried to see the `httpd -V` again and it told me I still had 2.4.10.

Can someone run me through fully uninstalling everything I may have installed onto my ubuntu and then properly setting up a mod_perl/apache httpd 2.2 system so I can start playing with it?

EDIT:
After deleting `/usr/local/apache2` and running `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2`, here's my results.

```
$ which apache2
/usr/sbin/apache2
$ which httpd
/bin/httpd
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:36:39
$ httpd -V
# same as previous in original text
$ perl -Mmod_perl2\ 999
mod_perl2 version 999 required--this is only version 2.000008.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Does this mean I've sucessfully done everything? Still worried about the httpd/apache thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(You could have just run `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2` and be done.)

It looks like you locally compiled and installed the `httpd` binary. If you still have the source true where you ran the `make` command, you can go in there and run `sudo make uninstall`. Hopefully, it's supported, and it will remove `httpd` from your system. If that doesn't work, hopefully, the files will have been installed into the folders in `/usr/local`, and you can remove `httpd`-related files manually.

Edit: It seems `make` installed `httpd` into `/bin/httpd`. After running `dpkg -S /bin/httpd` to verify it's not part of a package, you can just remove that file. Other than that, things look fine.

Comment: (I didn't know I could do that I'm an idiot, I'll do that after I get rid of everything.)


I did `make` stuff, but when I go to `sudo make uninstall`, it gives me this:


    `Make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.`

I'm also really bad at formatting comments

Comment: Check to see if `/usr/local/bin` has a file named `httpd`. If so, removing that will get rid of the main binary. You may also want to remove any files in `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: In my `/usr/local/` I found `apache2` folder which I've just removed manually (simply deleting it works right?). My `/usr/local/bin` has nothing with httpd, neither does my `/usr/local/lib`. Should I go ahead with the `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2` now?

Comment: Just deleting it *should* at least help. Yes, go ahead with the command.

Comment: I've made an edit about what happened